# Trying to select single documents from mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We have a rudimentary versioning system in a collection that uses a field (`pageId`) as a root key.  Subsequent versions of this page have the same `pageId`.  This allows us to very easily find all versions of a single page.

How do I go about running a query that returns only the `lastModified` document for each distinct `pageId`.

In psuedo-code you could say:

```
For each distinct pageId
sort documents based on lastModified descending
and return only the first document
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and an expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aggregation pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for that.

- [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) - Sorts all input documents and returns them to the pipeline in sorted order.
- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) - Groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping.
- [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) - Returns the value that results from applying an expression to the first document in a group of documents that share the same group by key.

Example:

```
db.getCollection('t01').aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {'lastModified': -1}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$pageId",
            element1: { $first: "$element1" },
            element2: { $first: "$element2" },
            elementN: { $first: "$elementN" },
        }
    }
]);
```